# How to solve a problem with different results in SAS and R due to a number representation issue

Tags: r, sas

I have a huge dataset in SAS and I'm trying to reproduce it in R.
I will focus on just a single column with BMI score.

In SAS, this is numeric column with 8.2 format.
In R - it is a numeric column which is then rounded to 2 decimal places by round(x, 2).

The formula for BMI is: weight/((height*0.01)**2)

When I'm comparing both datasets by typing sas==r, I'm getting all TRUE's but just one case...

SAS: 34.38
R: 34.37

Let's have a look at this case and see raw values:

Weight:  88
Height: 160

Result in SAS: 34.375
Result in R: 34.375

Looks the same, but for R this is not true:

```
> 88/((160*0.01)**2) == 34.375
> [1] FALSE

> options(digits = 22)
> 88/((160*0.01)**2) == 34.375
[1] 34.37499999999999289457
```

When I'm trying to round, it gives:

```
> round(88/((160*0.01)**2), 2)
[1] 34.36999999999999744205
```

so

```
> options(digits=7)
> round(88/((160*0.01)**2), 2)
[1] 34.37
```

I tried to play with mpfr library - without success.
I tried something like this:

```
> round(as.numeric(format(round(88/((160*0.01)**2), 3), nsmall = 3)), 2)
[1] 34.38
```

but when applied to the entire dataset this ruins other cases.

I changed the format in SAS to see more decimal digits and what I see is exactly: 34.37500

I'm going to give up... Is there any way to make both results exactly the same?

I can see that SAS and R share the same number representation issue, for instance 1-0.9 <> 0.1, and 0.01 is not 0.01 but

```
> options(digits=22)
> 0.01
[1] 0.01000000000000000020817
```

For my dataset, SAS and R agree in 99.99% with this one exception...

Any help, advice? :) Perhaps there is some options I could set, or a smart woarkound?

The output can be character. I'm exporting it to CSV, so I don't care about it.

Comment: Is there any problem with rounding to slightly greater precision in `R` and then rounding again?  *E.g.*, `round(round(88/((160*0.01)**2), 3), 2)`.

Comment: @whuber, no in this case the issue is in 0.01^2, it's machine precision larger than 0.0001

Comment: @Aksakal The issue is how SAS converts floats into decimal encoded values for storage in its database. We are, in effect, trying to reverse-engineer that process. The double-rounding procedure is one guess concerning what SAS does. What evidence do you have that SAS is doing something different?

Comment: @whuber, my guess is that SAS, like some other systems such as Oracle, use binary-decimal format, instead of IEEE 754 floating point when reals are specified as w.d format like NUMERIC 8.2. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal this is from IBM era when SAS was developed

Comment: @Aksakal You are talking only about data storage formats.  Internally SAS uses IEEE floats: see www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/235-29.pdf.  It sounds like your first comment "no..." is just speculation. (BTW, I'm quite familiar with BCD--I used to write Assembly language programs on IBM mainframes.)

Comment: @whuber, yes, it was speculation. I found the specification here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm SAS on WinTel uses IEEE with 80 bits, and IBM FP on mainframes My R 64bit seems to use the standard IEEE 64 bit precision, not the extended one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad news is that IEEE floating-point numbers such the one you use in R is generally not going to be exactly the same as NUMERIC 8.2 in SAS. The number will match in cases where the results are integer.

The floating point numbers will appear to match only due to the implicit conversion. For instance, how do you compare the numbers in SAS and R? You have to get them into one system, SAS or R, then there will be some kind of conversion involved either when you read the data or when you compare them. So, this implicit conversion will *hide* the difference between data formats, but the difference will still show up in some cases.

In your case, look at this example to see how to get the numbers to be the same, sort of:

```
   > height=160
> weight=88
> x=weight/(height**2*0.0001)
> x
[1] 34.375
> round(x,2)
[1] 34.38
> options(digits=22)
> round(x,2)
[1] 34.38000000000000255795
> round(x,2)
[1] 34.38000000000000255795
> options(digits=5)
> round(x,2)
[1] 34.38
```

UPDATE:
It [appears](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm) that SAS on Windows/Intel will use [x86 extended precsision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) for floating point, i.e. 80 bits real numbers. On the other hand, R appears to use IEEE 754 standard format, i.e. 64bit floating point. I might be wrong on this one, but that's what I see on my computer:

```
> .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
```

If R was using 80 bit reals, then I'd expect that to be $1.18×10^{4932}$.

Thus, it's impossible to guarantee that SAS and R on Windows/Intel will exactly match in every case by tweaking the code in general. If you have a large data set it's likely that whatever trick you use would fail in one case or another.

Therefore, you have to write the code in such a way that it doesn't matter whether the numbers match exactly or not.

Comment: The first time, it must be `round(x,20)`, right? Strangely, `options(digits=22)` didn't change anything on my R system, so I could not reproduce it.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch, sorry, I skipped a few lines in my post, added them back.

Comment: Dear Aksakal, thank you very much for this explanation. After applying this smart form of the formula, the mentioned case has been fixed, but other one has been broken...

What is interesting - again, ALL but ONE cases agree. Now the incorrect result is for the following input data:

Comment: data: weight: 56, height: 160. SAS raw = 21.875 (00), R raw: x <- 56/(160**2*0.0001). x == 21.875 [1] TRUE. After rounding (22 digits):  round(x, 2) [1] 21.87999999999999900524, (7 digits): round(x, 2) [1] 21.88. But SAS rounded: 21.87. So now the SAS result is less than R one.

Comment: BTW, thank you very much for showing me the trick with powers in the formula. It helped me a lot, without "dirty workarounds". Is there a common rule your solution follows?

Comment: @Bastian, there's no common rule. The only thing is that if you rely on the number of decimal digits somehow, then when using binary internal formats you run into issues usually. In this case 0.01 brought my attention.